# Passing in 'ID' with Rails form_for using Angular JS Ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, find, form-for, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ng-repeat` to create an index of records within a Rails view, on this index I'm trying to implement a button to update a particular record. The problem is I need to pass the correct id through to the Rails controller. I'm getting an error when I attempt to pass the record id through with  `'{{swim_record.id}}!'` , using string interpolation via Angular.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat='swim_record in SwimRecords | orderBy:predicate.value:reverse |
  filter:search'>
   <td>
     <a ng-href='/swim_records/{{swim_record.id}}'>
      {{swim_record.last_name}}
     </a>
   </td>
   <td>{{swim_record.first_name}}</td>
   <td class = 'hidden-xs'>{{swim_record.check_in | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</td>
   <th class = 'hidden-xs'>{{swim_record.lmsc}}</td>
   <td>
    <%= bootstrap_form_for Swimmer.find_by_id("{{swim_record.id }}!".to_i) do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :last_name, value: "Hat" %>
     <%= f.submit 'Check Out', class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is an extremely flexible and powerful framework but as they say, with great power comes great responsibility (/cliche). Although it may be a great addition to your web stack, you have to really understand what AngularJS does and the goal it tries to achieve.

I don't think the AngularJS team does a good job at marketing their product. On several of their pages they tell you to use AngularJS however you want, boasting their MVW ( model view whatever ) slogan. Their front page needs to boldly state what AngularJS is and what it tries to do but instead all I see is self praise. Sorry "HTML enhanced for web apps!" is not a good description...

In addition, their site says this dangerous little phrase

> "Add as much or as little of AngularJS to an existing page as you
>   like. Many other frameworks require full commitment. "

Unfortunately, this made many developers (myself included) see AngularJS as a drop in library that will seamlessly work with your old development styles and practice. I made this fatal mistake when I tried to mix the standard Rails MVC and ERB with AngularJS late into development at my summer internship. But I digress...

> The core thing to remember here is that the vanilla Rails 4 stack does
>   server side MVC, while AngularJS goes for client side MVC.

In a nutshell, vanilla Rails will build and embed your view on the server, while on the other hand AngularJS will build and embed your view client side.

Don't let this deter your from using Rails in combination with AngularJS though. You just can't mix and match AngularJS and ERB well. If you want to continue using AngularJS I'd recommend exposing json API endpoints with Rails and avoid using any <% %> embedding unless where absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you shall not mix server and client side code like that. server side code executes before angular `ng-repeat` starts. you have to understand how it works. server side is rendering html and sends to browser, where angularjs renders this html again. so you cannot get `swim_record.id` like that. I suggest to use server side language for API only, angularjs will handle rest